# Keras - functional and sequential model give different results

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I implemented two models, one time using the sequential way and one time with the functional API. Now the both models give different results, which kind of makes no sense to me.
I cannot figure out, what the problem is. Any ideas or solutions?

Here both models:

Sequential Model:

```
model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE +1, EMBEDDING_SIZE, mask_zero= True)  
model.add(embedding_layer)

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences= True))),
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(NUM_LABELS, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_sents_padded, train_labels_padded, batch_size=4, epochs=10, 
validation_data=(dev_sents_padded, dev_labels_padded))

score, acc = model.evaluate(dev_sents_padded, dev_labels_padded)
print("\nAccuracy: ", acc)
```

Functional Model:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,))  
embedding = Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE +1, EMBEDDING_SIZE, mask_zero= True)(inputs)

left = LSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=True)(embedding)
right = LSTM(HIDDEN_SIZE, go_backwards=True, return_sequences=True) 
(embedding)

left_right = concatenate([left, right])

left_right = TimeDistributed(Dense(NUM_LABELS, activation='softmax')) 
(left_right)

combined_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=left_right)

combined_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
metrics=['accuracy'])

combined_model.fit(
train_sents_padded,
train_labels_padded,
batch_size=4,
epochs=10,
validation_data=(dev_sents_padded, dev_labels_padded)
)

score, acc = combined_model.evaluate(dev_sents_padded, dev_labels_padded)
print("\nBidirectional LSTM Accuracy: ", acc)
```

+++
Summaries:

Sequential model:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, None, 50)          26150     
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, None, 100)         40400     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, None, 61)          6161      
=================================================================
Total params: 72,711
Trainable params: 72,711
Non-trainable params: 0 `
```

Functional model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to   
========================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)      (None, 34)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________
embedding_2 (Embedding)   (None, 34, 50)       26150       input_1[0][0]                    
______________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)             (None, 34, 50)       20200       embedding_2[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)             (None, 34, 50)       20200       embedding_2[0][0]                
_________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)(None, 34, 100)      0           lstm_2[0][0]                     
                                                             lstm_3[0][0]                     
 ___________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDistrib (None, 34, 61)  6161    concatenate_1[0][0]              
=====================================================================
Total params: 72,711
Trainable params: 72,711
Non-trainable params: 0`
```

+++
If I change `VOCAB_SIZE + 1` to `VOCAB_SIZE` in the seqential model the acc is 59, but only on every third run??

Comment: can you please elaborate more on `both models give different results`

Comment: Also for both models share the `summary()` output.

Comment: Your are using `fit` with  `shuffle=True` (default value), then your are training with batchs that are different, then I guess that makes those  differences. Try setting all the seeds (numpy, python ....)  to a common number, [see](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2743)

Comment: I think you are ignoring that both models won't be initialized with the exact same weights, so the results will differ.

Comment: I changed shuffle to False and still get different results. I already set the random seed to 5 before.
The sequential model gives an acc of 48 and the functional model of 64.
I will add the summary to the code above @Vikash Singh.